# Import a CSV file which its name is changing everyday into SQLite without any external tool

Tags: bash, sqlite, csv

I would like to import a CSV file with a timestamp in its filename. I want to do this by running the SQLite script file without any external modification (like using bash or another programming tool to copy the target CSV file to somewhere and rename it). The file name changes every day. So each day a different CSV file should be imported to the SQLite database file. The file name pattern looks like below:

abc_17-07-2021.csv
abc_18-07-2021.csv
abc_19-07-2021.csv

I would like to have a solely SQLite file script and run it on SQLite with it.
e.g. $ sqlite3 < example.sql

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Are there any more conditions on these files (such that: always the latest one by change date should get imported)?

Comment: All the solutions I tried using external tools before running a sqlite script, so I do not know how I can use a variable for a file name in the script. the file name has a timestamp so it would be enough to snap the filename with time. Yes the I need to import the latest file with the timestamp.

Comment: Then please share your attempts to gather the file with the latest timestamp

Comment: As I said "I do not have anything as SQL script". I don't think I need to share my third party tools attempt since I wonder "if" there is a way to accomplish that by using solely sqlite script.

Comment: Is your question solely **if** there is a way to do so? Then: yes, there is a way

Comment: my question was "if" there is a way todo so by only using sqlite script, nothing else (It is still there)

Answer (score 0):

if you do not want an external tool to use with your SQlite file, a simple way would be for the `.csv` to be exported to a folder where no other non relevant to this scenario file will be added to the folder, and when you import you should be able to use a wildcard `abc_*.csv` to import.

Comment: can you use it * on an import command in a SQL script file for sqlite3? I have multiple different file names with time stamps too ...

Comment: If this works, then you can specify different file names which need to be imported also.